# Edited: how to play large embedded videos from my own server?

Tags: video-streaming

I've edited this post to better fit the scope of Stackoverflow:

I have very large video files-500-600Meg each that I want to play from my own server.  I figured it was as simple as uploading the video and clicking to the url, but when i do that, the quicktime player comes up in my browser, but after two minutes I give up because it looks like it is trying to buffer the whole video before playing-or something?

What do I need to be able to embed my own videos on my own server and have them start playing quickly when a user clicks play?

Thanks!
Joel

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You may be better off posting this to serverfault...

Comment: Understood Tommie.  I realize this is outside the scope of the normal questions here.  Thanks for that recommendation.  I wasn't really sure where to take my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you check out [Kaltura](http://corp.kaltura.com/), they have both an open source solution to host and embed videos on your site, or use their paid services.

Their package includes both the server side, and a customizable Flex player.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to do this with rtmp, not http. QT will download the entire video, and nobody does it like that anymore.

Wowza has development versions that will let you test, or there are any number of video cdns that will do this for you.